# How to allow enable the weekends as working period in gantt project?

Tags: project-management, gantt

My question is similar to this one: [How can I enable a weekend as working period?](https://code.google.com/p/ganttproject/issues/detail?id=794) (no answers).

I want to plan a wedding in gantt project, where all days are considered working days. How can I do that? I have fiddled with options, but didn't found anything about weekends.

Answer (score 8):

You can go to Project->Proprietes->Calendar Project and there you can choose weekend's days

Comment: As of 2016 this answer is correct and works. Verified with **Gantt Project 2.7.2**.

Answer (score 5):

"I figured it out. There seems to be no way of changing the weekends after a project is started, but there is an option when you start a new project. I just created a new project and imported the previous schedule."

taken from: " http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?59865-GanttProject-Weekends "

Hope this helps, it should be setup before your project

Answer (score 2):

You can change working days (even in existing project) by changing settings of your **Project Calendar** and adding working hours for Saturday and Sunday.

See: https://support.office.com/client/Change-working-days-for-the-project-calendar-323ff403-a676-428c-be11-6942bfb7210c

Comment: External links can break, in which case this would be more of a hint than an answer.  It would be better to include the essential information here and use the link just for attribution and further reading.

Comment: I know its old, but I want to make a comment for anyone thinking about clicking on that link -- DONT!!! This question is about 'GanttProject' but the link refers to a Microsoft product. Two different things.

Answer (score 1):

I have planned many projects where tasks were permitted to be worked on over weekends. It is just a matter of setting the correct working time for the resources assigned to the task. If the resource(s) assigned are permitted to work on Saturday and Sunday then any tasks to which they are assigned will automatically be scheduled on those days.

How you set the working time for resources differs depending on which version of Project you are using. It changed slightly from MS-P 2010 onwards.

In both versions you go to the Resource Sheet, select the resource you want to modify and double-click on their calendar (right hand side of sheet). A common source of confusion is that the calendar is named the same as the Project's calendar, but when selected from the Resource Sheet is specific and personal to that user alone.

Having opened the resource's calendar's Change Working Time dialog it now differs depending on verison. In 2010 onward you go to the Working Week tab and enter a new [default] entry, then select the "Details" button and ensure you have selected all days on which the user is working. Accept the changes and ensure the dates are correct for the period of time the resource is working the new hours. You can add as many rows describing non-standard hours as you want...

On prior versions of MS-P, if I can remember correctly, you need to select Sat and Sun in the column headers of the calendar box and then click the radio button indicating Working Days or Non-Standard Working Days (in which case you need to manually enter the hours they work on the selected days).

Typically I have normal working resources, set up the usual way, and then specific weekend-working resources who work weekend shifts to get stuff done, but do not work normal weekdays. So I create two (or more) different resources, one with weekday working and one with weekend working. When I assign a weekend-working-only resource to a task MS-P will only schedule it to be worked on over the weekend. But you could easily mix and match within a single resource...

These kinds of changes can be done at any time during a project- If you suddenly realise you need to get something done over a weekend, just apply a resource to it that can work over the weekend and the task will be scheduled over a weekend. Changed your mind? Just allocate a different (non-weekend working) resource and the task will be scheduled for the working week (you'll have to recalcuate/levle the plan obviously, it won't just happen automatically)

Comment: It appears that the OP was not using MS Project, his question specifies GanttProject.

Comment: Doh! Missed that bit of vital info. That's 10 mins of my life I won't get back :)

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution. On Calender you can change the properties for the 24 hours calender. Then you enter the standard hour and select treat "sunday as standard" and treat "saturday as standard". You have to enter the working hours again but, each time you select it. Then I  assigned to all ressources the 24hours calender and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Project > Properties > Duration > change number of days in a month to 31 instead of the default 20.

Answer (score 0):

how to add an occasional weekend to be a working weekend?

You can go to Project->Properties->Calendar
go to One-off tab
click on Add
put in the target saturday or sunday
Change the type from "holiday" to "working" day
then
Continue to charge forward in life with a smile